Conditions such that $\text{Cov}(X, ZY)= 0$ for $X\sim Y \sim U(-1,1)$ and $P(Z=1) = P(Z=-1) =1/2$
Say I have three random variables $X\sim Y \sim U(-1,1)$, and a third one $P(Z=1) = P(Z=-1) =1/2$. What condition on these three variables must I have so that I can say $\text{Cov}(X, ZY)= 0$? I know
$$\text{Cov}(X, ZY) = \mathbb{E}(XYZ)- E(X)E(ZY) = \mathbb{E}(XYZ),$$
so I need $$\mathbb{E}(XYZ)=0.$$ Now, If I have mutual independence, certainly this will be $0$ since then $$\mathbb{E}(XYZ)= \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)\mathbb{E}(Z) = 0.$$ But does pairwise independence suffice for these particular variables, because $YZ = Z$ or $YZ = -Z$, and $X$ would be independent of both in that case and therefore independent of $YZ$, so $$\mathbb{E}(XYZ)= \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(YZ)=0.$$
Is this correct? And is it true that in general one would need mutual independence for
$$\mathbb{E}(XYZ)= \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)\mathbb{E}(Z),$$ and not only pairwise?

The condition is that marginal distributions match and $E[XYZ]=0$, equivalently, $E[XY|Z=-1]=E[XY|Z=1]$. Pairwise independence does not always work: Take $X,Y$ independent and define $Z=1$ if $XY>0$ and $Z=-1$ else. On the other hand, you do not need $X$ and $Y$ to be independent to satisfy the conditions.

Pairwise independence is not enough: Consider $X,Y$ independent and uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$. Let $\tilde X=-1$ if $X<0$ and $\tilde X=1$ if $X\ge 0$, and define $\tilde Y$ analogously.
Finally, let $Z=\tilde X \tilde Y$. I leave it to you to check that $Z$ is independent of $X$ and that $Z$ is independent of $Y$.
Then $XYZ=\lvert X Y\rvert$ and a direct computation gives $$\mathbb E(X Y Z) = \frac14\neq 0.$$
Your argument fails because $YZ = 1_{Z=1} Y-1_{ Z=-1} Y$ (note you mixed up $Y$ and $Z$ there), and while $X$ is both independent of $Y$ individually and of $Z$ individually, it does not follow that it is independent of a product of functions for these variables (for this joint independence is sufficient).
